# $slice operator of mongoDB not working in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have got this mongoDB query:

```
db.b_activity.find(
    {token_id:"71e32267108b163ccdd3f59ba06c66674b295499"},
    {activity_log:{$slice: -1}}
).pretty();
```

It gets all the desired results in the mongoDB terminal, but when I write the same query in PHP, it fetches the complete array every time.

MY PHP query:

```
$get_current_activity = $this->mongo_b_employee->b_activity->findOne(
    array('token_id'=>$token_id),
    array("activity_log" => array('$slice' => -1))
);
```

Any suggestions where I am doing something wrong?

PS: I am just trying to access the last array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for [`MongoDB\Collection::findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-findOne/) is slightly different from the "shell". It requires the `"projection"` key in the `$options` as the second argument:

```
$get_current_activity=$this->mongo_b_employee->b_activity->findOne(
    array('token_id'=>$token_id),
    array(
      "projection" => array( "activity_log" => array('$slice' => -1) )
    )
)
```

Comment: @HarjeevSingh Lots of people do. The same thing is true of other language drivers. It has actually been brought up that the shell methods should be more reflective of what the language drivers actually need for options.